# ImportError in Python 3.8.6

Tags: python, importerror, relative-import

I am using python 3.8.6 to build a simple web app with the module Flask and the folder structure looks exactly like this:

```
web-app
 ├── main.py
 └── site
     ├── __init__.py
     ├── auth.py
     └── models.py
```

In `__init__.py` there is a function called `create_app()` and this function must be accessed by my `main.py`.

```
# site/__init__.py
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.SECRET_KEY = ""
    return app
enter code here
```

In my `main.py` I am importing the `create_app()` like this:

```
# main.py
from .site import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But when I try to run my `main.py`, raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/website/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .site import create_app
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I've already try to import without the dot before the folder's name, like `from site import create_app`, but that also didn't work, the error message just changes to `ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'site' (C:\Python38\lib\site.py)`.

Comment: Maybe this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Comment: Did you try it removing the "." form ```.site``` it seems unlikely it would be there

Comment: Yeap! As I said, I tried to remove the ".", but the errors changes to ```ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'site' (C:\Python38\lib\site.py)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

`from web-app.site import create_app`

An from a directory one level up run:

`python -m web-app.main`

There are apparently built-in module named `site` in Python, so there's a bit of name collision here.

Comment: Module names cannot contain minus signs, will raise an SyntaxError.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly. I changed the name to "webapp" (without the "-"). Just a doubt, there is some way to run inside of the webapp folder? Maybe change some import or anything else?

Comment: You can change `site` to something else or put it into another module, so you avoid a collision with a built-in module with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Add a file named `__init__.py` inside the `web-app` folder (you can leave it empty). You then should be able to do `from .site import create_app`